# How to play Watermark video in order manner using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, watermark

I want to play a watermark video one by one in output video using ffmpeg.

Below command set 4 videos as watermark on image and create output video but watermark video plays in parallel.

```
String[] cmd={"-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/trasprent_bg.png","-i",videourl_1.mp4,"-i",videourl_2.mp4,"-i",videourl_3.mp4,"-i",videourl_4.mp4,"-i",image_collage.png,"-filter_complex","[1:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266[tfg];[2:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266[bfg];[3:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266[threefg];[4:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266[fourfg];[5:v]scale=-1:-1[colage];[0:v][tfg]overlay=2:2[o1];[o1][bfg]overlay=272:2[o2];[o2][threefg]overlay=2:272[o3];[o3][fourfg]overlay=272:272[o4];[o4][colage]overlay=0:0","-an","videoCrop37.mp4"};
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter timestamps for the other videos.

> String[]
>   cmd={"-loop","1","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/trasprent_bg.png","-i",videourl_1.mp4,"-i",videourl_2.mp4,"-i",videourl_3.mp4,"-i",videourl_4.mp4,"-i",image_collage.png,"-filter_complex","[1:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266[tfg];[2:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266,setpts=PTS+X/TB[bfg];[3:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266,setpts=PTS+Y/TB[threefg];[4:v]scale=500:500,crop=266:266,setpts=PTS+Z/TB[fourfg];[5:v]scale=-1:-1[colage];[0:v][tfg]overlay=2:2:eof_action=pass[o1];[o1][bfg]overlay=272:2:eof_action=pass[o2];[o2][threefg]overlay=2:272:eof_action=pass[o3];[o3][fourfg]overlay=272:272:eof_action=pass:shortest=1[o4];[o4][colage]overlay=0:0","-an","videoCrop37.mp4"};

For the 2nd, 3rd and 4th videos, `setpts=PTS+T/TB` filter has been added, where T is the delay in seconds for that video's start time. If the duration of the 4 videos is 6,3,11,5 seconds then X=6, Y=9 (6+3) and Z=20 (6+3+11).

Comment: command run but output video create with 00:00:00 second. 4 video have 9 second duration so set value of X=9,Y=18,Z=27.

Comment: Try edited cmd.

Comment: edited command run infinity

Comment: Which ffmpeg version? There's a bug with shortest in some older versions

Comment: ffmpeg version n3.0.1

Comment: Need 3.4 or newer.

Comment: currently not possible to update ffmpeg version because my hole project build on 3.0.1.please tell me how to  possible it with ffmpeg 3.0.1 version.please help me.

Comment: After `-loop 1` add `-t N` where N = duration of all 4 videos added